# Dirac Delta does not converge

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have trouble evaluating a simple integral in Mathematica. I have the code:

```
integrand = f[1/x] DiracDelta[-r0 + rm - rm x + rp x]
Assuming[{rp, rm, r0} \[Element] Reals && rp > 0 && rm > 0 && r0 > 0, Integrate[integrand, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]]
(*Integral of ... does not converge on ...*)
```

This surprised me, since using the [usual dirac delta identity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) is
$$
\delta(g(x)) = \sum_i \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|} \ \ \ \ \text{where}\ x_i\ \text{are roots of}\ g
$$
We can say
$$
\delta(-r0 + rm - rm \ x + rp \ x) = \frac{\delta(x- \frac{r0+rm}{rm-rp})}{|rp-rm|}
$$
and inserting this into Mathematica I get the "correct" result:

```
integrand2 = DiracDelta[-((-r0 + rm)/(rm - rp)) + x]/Abs[-rm + rp] f[1/x]
    Assuming[{rp, rm, r0} \[Element] Reals && rp > 0 && rm > 0 && r0 > 0, Integrate[integrand2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]]
    (*f[(-rm + rp)/(r0 - rm)]/Abs[rm - rp]*)
```

My question is why doesn't the first code integrate to the correct value?

Comment: The support of `DiracDelta[-r0 + rm - rm x + rp x]` is `x==(-r0 + rm)/(rm - rp)`. This does not make sense if `rm==rp` in both cases you considered.

Comment: `rm = 1 + I; rp = 1; r0 = 1; integrand2 = 
 DiracDelta[-((-r0 + rm)/(rm - rp)) + x]/Abs[-rm + rp] f[1/x];
Integrate[integrand2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` results in `f[1]`. All this would be funny if it isn't  so sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica's `DiracDelta` shows problems with scaling property.

As a workaround try

```
dirac = Function[x, Exp[-(x^2/(2 eps))]/Sqrt[2 Pi eps]] 

Assuming[{rp, rm, r0} \[Element] Reals && rp > 0 && rm > 0 && r0 > 0 &&eps > 0, 
Integrate[1 dirac [-r0 + rm - rm x + rp x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]]
(*1/Abs[rm - rp]*)
```

which gives the correct scaling factor.

The integral you asked for follows to `f[(rp-rm)/(rm-r0)]/Abs[rm - rp]`

Hope it helps!

Comment: The result of `Assuming[{rp, rm, r0} \[Element] Reals && rp > 0 && rm > 0 && r0 > 0 &&
   eps > 0, 
 Integrate[
  1 dirac[-r0 + rm - rm x + rp x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
  GenerateConditions -> True]]` is the same! We see the implementation of `DiracDelta` in Mathematica leaves much to be desired.